# how to setup hmail server with a django project

Tags: python, django, hmail-server

I am trying to setup open source hmailserver with a django project. I have set up the server according to documentation. But I dont know how to use it with django.

For gmail i was using this setting:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_HOST_USER = Email
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = Password
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = Email
SERVER_EMAIL = Email
```

I tried changing the settings like this, But didn't worked:

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'something.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 25
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'info@something.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'info@something.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'info@something.com'
```

hmail credentials are:

```
My domain name:  something.com
My account name: info@somthing.com
```

How to configure it with django?

Comment: You need to ask `something.com` for their settings. host will probably still start with `smtp` but its not really anything we can help with

Comment: something.com is a dummy domain. Can i create a local server without subscribing to any domain?

Comment: I'm sure its possible to set up your own email server, that task is too broad for stackoverflow though

Answer (score 1):

Did you add EMAIL_BACKEND?

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'no-reply@*****'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'

# Port for sending e-mail.
EMAIL_PORT = 25

# Optional SMTP authentication information for EMAIL_HOST.
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '*****'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = False
```

Answer (score 0):

SERVER_EMAIL should be the name of the computer which hMailServer runs on (usually it's not the same as the domain name).